# 360 degrees heading calculation between two points

Tags: leaflet

I'm using [Leaflet + Leaflet's rotate-branch](https://github.com/fnicollet/Leaflet/tree/rotate-master) to rotate my map application.

```
map.setBearing(angle_deg);
```

is the function to do so. `angle_deg` has to be between 0 and 359 to simulate any desired angle. I want the map to follow and rotate in relation to the users current position and walking direction.

In order to avoid math, I wanted to use [Leaflet.GeometryUtil](http://makinacorpus.github.io/Leaflet.GeometryUtil/global.html#bearing) to do the calculations for me, but only was able to find the functions `bearing()` and `computeAngle()`, which yield the same result: **horizontal heading between two coordinates** (0 up to 180 clockwise and back to 0 again in axial symmetry with a minus sign).

How can I transform this into a full 360 degree value?

To further illustrate:

```
      0                   360/0
  -90   90       to     270   90 
    +/-180                 180
```

Could I just add 360 to all negative values and be fine?

Answer (score 3):

In order to get a 360° value, I just had to substract the horizontal angle from 360.

```
angle_degree = 360-angle
```

Now the map is rotating in the direction the user is heading to.

Comment: Are you able to mark your answer as the solution? :)

Answer (score 1):

The code should look like this:

```
let heading = (360 + angle) % 360;
```

resulting in:

```
(360 + 45)    % 360 // => 405 % 360 = 45
(360 + (-160)) % 360 // => 200 % 360 = 200
```